# Open links from newly received emails automatically

Tags: email, hyperlink, gmail

is there are program or script or anything that will make my email client/webmail to open webpage links from newly received emails automatically?

If someone knows or can make a add-on for thunderbird or make this to work I don't mind paying. Just I need links that are in emails I receive to be automatically opened in default internet browser tabs.

Comment: This seems like a poor idea since you could easily open phishing emails and such that you definitely dont want to follow

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is I very very much doubt it. If there ever was one created it would most probably be removed by most download source providers as there is a fairly huge security risk there.

Additionally, aside from the security factor you have a simple load factor to account for. I regularly make newsletters for clients, each with a link to a text version, a online version, a link for the logo and so forth... So if you did have such a plugin you would also open these links, which seams crazy. Additionally, remember the Unsubscribe link for emails, on some you are asked to confirm on others you click(/open), your taken off. Which would be very undesired.

I do understand you probably have a reason X for doing this, like because its a in house email system which creates reports and it does this and does that etc. I think most people here do understand there are sometimes very odd usage cases for things, but I don't think anyone will be able to assist you here, sorry!